# How to propperly exclude the Document Id property when saving a custom class to Firestore?

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

My custom class is designed to store the Document Id besides the relevant data.

```
data class Appointment(
    @DocumentId
    val UID: String,
    
    val date: Timestamp,
    val header: String
) {
    companion object {
        fun DocumentSnapshot.toAppointment() : Appointment? {
            try {
                val date = getTimestamp("date") ?: Timestamp(Date())
                val header= getString("header").toString()
                return Appointment(id, date, header)
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Error converting appointment", e)
                return null
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Reading a document to my class is no problem due to my custom `toAppointment` function, unfortunately I can't prevent firestore to write the `UID` data to firestore using the `add()` function:

```
val appointment = Appointment("", Timestamp(Date()), "Header")
docRef.collection("appointments").add(appointment)
```

In Firestore the newly created document always have an UID-field (with an empty string).
I added the `@DocumentId` annotation as mentioned [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/DocumentId.html) - unfortunately this seems to only work with the `set()` function.

Thank you very much

Comment: If you think this is a bug, and you would like different behavior, I suggest filing an issue on GitHub.  https://github.com/firebase/firebase-android-sdk

Comment: Hey Doug,
can't tell if it is a bug since the official documentation says this annotation will work for "set()" explicitly, but saying nothing about "add()". Do you know a possibility to exclude a property of a custom class from getting written to Firestore?
Thank you very much.

Comment: It's hard to say without seeing your `Appointment` class, but you might want to also put an [`@Exclude()` annotation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/Exclude) in the field/getter/setter for the document ID.

Comment: Hey Frank, thank you for your comment. Actually my Appointment class is mentioned in my question at the very top :)
I already tried to add the `@Exclude` annotation - unfortunately it hasn't worked out.